# communication between service and directive: dependency or or events

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module, angularjs-directive

Problem: having several directives that communicate with a service/factory that communicate/log actions with a server.
Should I declare relations between them as a dependency

```
angular.module('someModule', [])
    .directive('someDir', ['logger', function ( logger ) {
        //...
    }])

    .service('logger', ['$http', function( $http ){
        //...
    }]);
```

or event-based relations?

```
angular.module('someModule', [])
    .directive('someDir', ['$rootScope', function ( $rootScope ) {
        $rootScope.$emit('someEvent');
        // ...
    }])

    .service('logger', ['$http', '$rootScope', function( $http, $rootScope ){
        $rootScope.$on('someEvent', function(){
            // ...
        });
        // ...
    }]);
```

What pros and cons except, i guess,  decoupling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some definite advantage of using eventing:

- Decoupling is the first as you highlighted.
- Events allows us to add more subscribers in the future. For example on `someEvent` you not only want to log something but also do something else, then create a subscriber to handle the new scenario.

Eventing does have some disadvantages:

- Execution is not linear anymore, hence debugging becomes a little difficult. Too many events and debugging can become a nightmare.
- This also affects code readability as you are not sure what exactly is happening just by reading parts of the code.
- We should not depend upon order of execution of events. If we want ordered execution eventing is not a right fit.

I personally use eventing for taking care of scenarios which are not part of main process flow. Logging is a good example of such a feature.